# How can I handle common string content on a multiplatform mobile app?

Tags: mobile, internationalization, localization

I'm working on a mobile app that has been developed for iOS and Android (both native), localised into over 10 languages. A lot of the static string content in the app is common between the two versions. Currently, the strings are stored in a shared spreadsheet, which is a terrible solution.

I would like to improve two things:

- Store all text content centrally in a safer way (and retrieve it via an API)
- Have some sort of lifecycle management for reviewing and translating strings

Is there a standard way to do this in multiplatform apps?